# Hide "Done" button on AdMob

Tags: ios, admob

Can I hide the "Done" button (as seen below) for 3 to 4 seconds in AdMob?

[image]

Comment: Separate questions should be posted separately. The image you posted doesn't seem to have much relevance to your question. Please expand upon your issue. What specifically is preventing you from hiding the "Done" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is something easily doable. The AdMob SDK doesn't give you a direct handle to that modal view.

If a callback was sent after the modal view was presented, you could recursively go through your view hierarchy looking for the UIButton with a 'Done' label and hide that. However, there's no callback that is fired after the full modal view is presented, only one that is called before.